# Parse Cloud Code to send push notification to group of users

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I want to send push notification when my data change to relational users. For example I have a group and its have 8 members.
So I need to send push notification to this 8 members with cloud code.what should I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with typing out someone else's answer this link [Cloud Code Push Notification Query to Array of PFUsers](https://www.parse.com/questions/cloud-code-push-notification-query-to-array-of-pfusers)

So lets say you update or add a new row to one of your classes, that class would have an array of the user object id's, then in the cloud code aftersave you would follow the example link listed above.

Might help you out you out.

You can also look at [channels for the Installation Class](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications-using-channels)

You could send a push from the client to this channel and to your 8 users.

Small code example of users who are subscribed to channel Giants

```
// Send a notification to all devices subscribed to the "Giants" channel.
PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setChannel:@"Giants"];
[push setMessage:@"The Giants just scored!"];
[push sendPushInBackground];
```

Again this example is in the link above, so you could probably go that route.